# Everytime Eclipse starts I get this error message (aptana plugin)

Tags: eclipse

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.jobs 4 2 2013-08-19 10:40:49.721
!MESSAGE An internal error occurred during: "Start Ruble bundle manager".
!STACK 0
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.io.File.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.aptana.scripting.model.BundleMonitor.beginMonitoring(BundleMonitor.java:107)
    at com.aptana.scripting.ScriptingActivator$1.run(ScriptingActivator.java:111)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:53)
```

I don't even code in Ruby. I use Aptana for my PHP work.

Comment: StackOverflow has a similar thread. You might find some useful suggestions there. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14133269/an-internal-error-occurred-during-start-ruble-bundle-manager

Answer (score 0):

You probably chanced something and Eclipse "lost" the info where this plugin came from.

Go to "Help" -> "Install New Software..." and add Aptana website there "http://download.aptana.com/studio3/plugin/install". If Aptana is already there, just rename it.